# Nonce update for multiple CREATEs in a single transaction when some fail

Tags: evm, nonce, yellow-paper, create

Suppose executing the bytecode of a smart contract in a particular (single) transaction leads to several `CREATE`'s in a row (triggered by the same smart contract). Is it true that the nonce of that smart contract gets raised by 1 with each `CREATE` regardless of whether the `CREATE`s fail (e.g. hit a `REVERT` during execution of its initcode or ran out of gas)?

There is no doubt that the nonce must change with every successful `CREATE` so as to assure that future creates in that transaction yield different addresses. But I'm not sure about what happens if a `CREATE` failed, although I expect that the nonce is raised regardless.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems the answer is **YES**: the nonce is updated at the moment `CREATE` starts regardless of success of the `CREATE`. Thanks to Franklin Delehelle for pointing me to the [relevant section of the geth codebase](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/2697e44d819377e39a781e5ab9f1814426b4b0f0/core/vm/evm.go#L419).

Here's a screenshot of the relevant bit of code:
[image]